# How do I create a barplot in R with a cumulative standard deviation?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a plot similar to the one attached by Lindfield et al. 2016. I'm familiar with the `ggplot` command in R with the format:

```
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x, y)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

However, I don't know how to make a cumulative se error for a stacked barplot; only one that employs a `position_dodge` command.

I know that there are disadvantages to using stacked bars with se errors, but for my data set, it is more presentable than using the unstacked barplots.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you get the cumulative standard errors in an appropriate way (I guess it depends on how your values are generated) but I think you need to do calculate them and store them in a second DF, for example if you have an initial data.frame created like this:

```
DF <- data.frame( x=c("a","a","b","b"),
                  sp=c("shark","cod","shark","cod"),
                  y=c(10,5,15,7),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE )
```

where y is the value associated with each species at each x point, then you'd create a second DF containing the lower and upper limits of your s.e. for each x value, eg

```
seDF <- data.frame( x=c('a','b'),
                    yl=c(12,18),
                    yu=c(17,24),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE )
```

Then you can create your plot with:

```
ggplot() +
 geom_bar( data=DF, mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,fill=sp),
           position="stack", stat="identity") +
 geom_linerange( data=seDF, mapping=aes(x=x, ymin=yl, ymax=yu) )
```

I used `geom_linerange` rather then `geom_errorbar` as it doesn't create crossbars at either end.

[image: Output of example code]

Comment: @tim-quimpo Did this solve the problem? Or was the query really about how to get the cumulative standard errors?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I understand the logic for the codes, and I think this will work for me. However, can you show again how you created the min y and max y values? The code in paragraph 2 is the exact code as paragraph 1. While in your ggplot command you have a dataframe that seDF and mapping aesthetics such as y1 and yu.

Comment: Sorry Tim. Copy and paste error. I've edited my answer to actually include the creation/structure of seDF. The creation of the min and max values might depend on how you estimated the values being presented. It might be possible to get he s.e. for sums of coefficients from whatever routine you used to do your analysis, or you might need to estimate them using a variance-covariance matrix between the parameters.I just made numbers up for demo graph purposes